# Java visible interface that can not be implemented

Tags: java, interface

I'm working on making a programming language that compiles to JVM bytecode, and it highly relies on interfaces as types. I need some way to make an interface private, but have other code still be able to access it, but not make something that implements it.

I was thinking about using abstract classes with a private constructor, so only the classes in the same file would be able to access it. The only problem is that it is impossible to extend multiple abstract classes at once. For example, the structure of a simple compiled program would be this:

```java
// -> Main.java
public class Main {
    public static MyInteger getMyInteger() {
        return new MyIntegerImpl(10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}

    private interface MyInteger {
        public int getValue();
    }

    private static class MyIntegerImpl implements MyInteger {
        private final int value;

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public MyIntegerImpl(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And another file, in which there is a problem:

```java
// -> OtherFile.java
public class OtherFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.MyInteger myInteger = Main.getMyInteger(); //Error: The type Main.MyInteger is not visible.
        System.out.println(myInteger.getValue());
    }

    //I do not want this to be allowed
    public static class sneakyInteger implements Main.MyInteger { //Error(Which is good)
        public int getValue() {
            System.out.println("Person accessed value");
            return 10;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why I want to do this is so one person can not mess up any other person's code by providing their own implementations of things that should be only implemented by that other person.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the method bodies? This code does not compile.

Comment: @ChrisGilardi You mean try `class` (package/private). That will make it only available to other classes in the same package. `protected` makes it available to sub-classes.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah, I realized after I posted that comment that it was incorrect, and then deleted it, but yeah that's what I meant.

Comment: I'm really confused what you're trying to do... seems like this question maybe too broad? What you're saying is you want to make a `type` that everyone can access but only the original person who made the `type` can use?

Comment: @RileyCarney yes.

Comment: @JacobG. I added the method bodies, but the point is it does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you should think again about what you are trying to do and change approach, but the answer for your question is to add to the interface some empty `void` method that is getting the parameter of the inner `private` class specific for the wrapper class

```
public class Test {
    private class InnerPrivateClass {
        private InnerPrivateClass() {}
    }

    public interface MyInteger {
        int getValue();

        void accept(InnerPrivateClass c);
    }

    private class MyIntegerImpl implements MyInteger {
        @Override
        public int getValue() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(InnerPrivateClass c) {}
    }
}
```

However, as I said, I don't like this and for me it means that your idea is broken